# Pod MissingSpecError, Ruby, Gem, Cocoapods etc

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

When I run `pod` I now get

```
$ pod
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
    2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.0_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.0_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.0_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/User1/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.0_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

I've tried reinstalling Cocoapods, removing all gems etc.

Somewhere there was a comment about this issue being caused by the wrong path of ruby being referenced, but which should be the "right" one? Everything worked for 4 years but now Pod can't run, I don't get it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[cocoapods not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904588/cocoapods-not-installing) has got it

1) `brew reinstall cocoapods`

(error message will come up regarding linking)

2) `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`

(to fix the link)

I have no idea why this was an issue to begin with as it could've worked using pure `gem` as well but I'm happy now

Comment: This did not work for me. Cocoapods continues to search the incorrect ruby version.