# flutter doctor not finding cocoa pods

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoa

I have an issue that tells me to install cocoapods using gem, but the **flutter doctor** couldn't find it.

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0 20A2411 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at /Users/kirandhoundiyal/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/apps/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/apps/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Volumes/apps/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Volumes/apps/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is
        different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see
        https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Volumes/apps/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Also `gem list pod` is giving an empty list but `sudo gem list pod` is giving this

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.10.0)
cocoapods-core (1.10.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4)
cocoapods-downloader (1.4.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.5.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
```

I am first time doing this stuff, need some help, what's wrong?

EDIT: `ruby -v` gives this `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]`

`which ruby` gives this - `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: I found the answer in old SO question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904588/cocoapods-not-installing

Comment: Also if you installed rubygems from brew you can install cocoapods from brew too. This fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 8):

I found that I had to first update gem itself:

`sudo gem update --system`

Then uninstall and reinstall Cocoapods:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Only then would flutter doctor stop complaining that cocoapods was not installed.

Comment: Fore me, just running `sudo gem update --system` worked, without reinstalling cocoapods.

Comment: this didn't solve it for me.  I have Ruby v3.2.2 on OSX v13.6.1

Answer (score 4):

First try this ;

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If it does not works for you.

Try this :(It works for me in macos Bigsur M1)

Check permission for the mentioned directory via:

```
ls -l /home/raphael/flutter/
```

If not, while being in the folder mentioned above, try to change permission on the folder via:

```
chown -R YOUR_USERNAME flutter
```

Run the first command again to verify that the apropriate user is now shown on the folder. Then try to create the project again.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac I installed cocoapods with command "brew install cocoapods" and solved the problem.

Comment: I tried this too.  still doctor won't recognise it

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving issues one by one. First resolve xcode issue using

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

After this
run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

===

If this not works give output of following commands. Also can you tell if brew is installed?

```
$ruby -v
===
$ which ruby
===
```

Comment: Homebrew is installed.  I am on mac mini M1  chip.

Comment: then you must have installed cocoapods using homebrew. uninstall older one and then can you just install using -- sudo gem install cocoapods.  after this run gem install ffi

Comment: I did above steps, but still same problem. I removed cocoapods from homebrew and reinstalled using gem.  ruby path given in Edit above question

Comment: I'm using brew.  `ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin22]` and `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`.  it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command successfully, then flutter can find the CocoaPods.

```
pod --version
```

If `pod` is a recognized command, and you have installed the CocoaPods via

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

You can add the gem installation directory to the path manually

```
export GEM_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY=$(gem environment | grep "\- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY" | grep -o '/.*')
export PATH="$GEM_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/bin:$PATH"
```

Currently, my ruby (installed via brew) version is `3.3.0` and the gem installation directory is `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0`