# Flutter - 'Xcode installation is incomplete', Missing CocoaPods installation

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, cocoapods

I run `flutter doctor` on my Mac with Xcode 13.0 but it prompted that 'CocoaPods didn't install'.

So, I tried `gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install cocoapods` but it gives me [Permission Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51126403/17673002).

I also tried HomeBrew, `brew install cocoapods` but no luck as I run into [Brew Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335801/17673002).

When I ran `flutter doctor` again, it gives `Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development`. Then, I deleted Xcode and CocoaPods to fresh start the installation. But it was not working.

I uninstalled HomeBrew and command line tools but it was unsuccessful.

Also, there are issues about flutter and android studio, and here is  the `flutter doctor` output:

[image: Terminal]

And here is my Android Studio project structure:
[image: AndroidStudio project structure]

Comment: please make it short and come to the point because it's difficult to read whole thing

Comment: Invalid data Clear Cache From Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

as the terminal suggests you, launch the following commands:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```