# Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed in mac M1 chip

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, swift5

I'm getting an error while trying to install the pods. I'm using a Mac with M1 chip and BigSir OS.

- xCode 13.2.1.
- Ruby 2.6.3p62
- Brew 3.5.5

  [!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.

Any idea about this? logs attached below

```
Error loading plugin file `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.1/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`.
```

Complete log

```
CompilationError - error executing "xcrun clang -dynamic -bundle               -undefined dynamic_lookup -multiply_defined suppress   -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC -L. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.6.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin20 -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -o \"/Users/kasunka/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.6.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.bundle\" \"/Users/kasunka/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.6.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c\" -lc -framework Security -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices ": pid 3611 exit 1
Renamed /Users/kasunka/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.6.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c to /Users/kasunka/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.6.0/Inline_OSXKeychain_5b2f8d1cd1bde9c4ff3fea49f09cd5c1.c.bad
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.6/lib/inline.rb:616:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.6/lib/inline.rb:854:in `inline'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/osx_keychain-1.0.2/lib/osx_keychain.rb:17:in `<class:OSXKeychain>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/osx_keychain-1.0.2/lib/osx_keychain.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.1/lib/keyring.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.1/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:92:in `block in safe_require'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:90:in `safe_require'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `map'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `/Library/Ruby/Gems` is wrong. Install your own ruby.

Comment: If the problem is solved, then please either answer your own question (in the Answer field) or delete the question, so as not to leave it hanging. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem, here is a link to a comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74130396/17279785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gem install cocoapods-keys`, then run `pod install` again.

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks.