# Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again

Tags: ios, swift, key, cocoapods

Keep having this error on trying to run `pod install`
I'm using an intel mac.

I'm running

1 - gem install cocoapods
2 - gem install cocoapods-keys

then try to install `pod install`

when I list cocoapods it shows cocoapods-keys

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods

cocoapods (1.11.3)
cocoapods-core (1.11.3)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.6.3)
cocoapods-keys (2.2.1)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)


Errors: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

---------------------------------------------
Error loading plugin file `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.1/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`.

'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------

[!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.
```

OBS: when I run `pod plugins installed` it gives an error and it shows that keys weren't installed as shown bellow

```
Error loading plugin file `/Users/felipeas/.gem/gems/cocoapods-keys-2.2.1/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`.

Installed CocoaPods Plugins:
    - cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
    - cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    - cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
    - cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
    - cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

Comment: Check your path, might be something like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74130396/5318223

Comment: I've got the exact same problem on an M1 macbook.  As far as I can tell, same setup on my Mac Mini works fine.  No idea why.  Have you solved this one yet?  Please update with an answer if so.

Comment: Couldn't solve it, I've installed Monterey on my mac and xcode 13.4.1 and its working fine now.